# Scripting.FileSystemObject running out of memory on Write method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code to write a string to a TXT file.

It works ok for files  <40mbs however the TXT i'm trying to save would be a bit bigger ~45mb and I'm getting the error "Out of memory" when getting to the .write line.

```
Private Sub SaveToTXT(FilePath As String, FileContents As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    FileManagementFactory.DeleteIfExists (FilePath)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FilePath)
    Call oFile.Write(FileContents)
    Call oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any idea how to bypass this problem?

Comment: use the OpenTextFile Method which would allow you to append to the file.  then you can split up the string and write it in chunks.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this.

```
Private Sub SaveToTXT(FilePath As String, FileContents As String)
    Dim nFileNum As Integer: nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Binary Lock Read Write As #nFileNum
    Put #nFileNum, , FileContents
    Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe writing each line is a lot slower than writing it all at once. I might try writing it each 10000 lines for example.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted, do you know how I could split it each N lines for example? so I write it in two or three .Writes instead of line by line?

Comment: There really is no other option. You could try ADO, but that is about all. The second option is to ditch VBA and use VB.Net to do what you need.

Comment: Any way you try to split the lines is going to take up more time. Splitting by n Rows would require you to capture a string to write by going say from character 40 using MID to character 500... that still requires a lot of looping.

Comment: If you use VB.NET, it has better handling for writing these kind of large files. VBA is basically VB.Net as an infant.

Comment: I'm trying to split it in 1,000,000 characters chunks, by doing MID(FileContents, i * 1000000, (i + 1) * 1000000) inside a loop

Comment: I take back my previous comment. You can use the write method and write n number of lines at a time. That will actually cause it to flush the memory buffer each time, but you would have to get a subset of the array of lines first and then squish them into a string. I'm not sure how much latitude you have there though. It might be that writing such a procedure actually takes longer than if you were just to write line by line.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally did, it separates the file in 20,000,000 character strings. In my test it seems to go pass the memory limit.

```
Private Sub SaveToTXT(FilePath As String, FileContents As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim l As Long
    Dim CharactersPerChunk As Long
    CharactersPerChunk = 20000000
    FileManagementFactory.DeleteIfExists (FilePath)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ' A lot faster than ADODB.Stream
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FilePath)
    l = 0
    While l < Len(FileContents) / CharactersPerChunk
        Call oFile.Write(Mid(FileContents, (l * CharactersPerChunk) + 1, CharactersPerChunk))
        l = l + 1
    Wend
    Call oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try the binary write function I posted after my last edit? It had a few errors, but I fixed those.

Comment: I didn't have time to try it, I'll try to measure which is faster before accepting an answer.

Comment: You should go ahead and try out the updated code I just posted. It is super efficient and runs faster than the one above that chunks it out (~171 ms vs 343 ms) Let me know if it also solves the memory problem.